# How to return array value (from PHP) using a MySql query

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a PHP array:

```
<?php $array = ['small','medium', 'big']; ?>
```

I have a table (size_table) with id and size_id (size_id = 0, means 'small', size_id = 1, means 'medium' and so on).

I need to write a SELECT query that returns all records, but uses the $array for values:

```
id | size
1  | small -> the size_id in the table is 0
2  | big -> the size_id in the table is 2
3  | medium -> the size_id in the table is 1
```

So, it will be something like:

```
SELECT id, ($array['size_id']) AS smart FROM size_table;
```

Of course this does not work, it is just for explaining mi goal.

By the way, I can have lots of size_id. They can be 20 or even 50.

Comment: Are you saying you want to _translate_ your numeric IDs into the corresponding keywords? Well then _ideally_, you should not have those in a PHP array, but in a second database table - so that you can properly JOIN this data together.

Comment: If you want to do this directly in the query - then you will need to build the query dynamically, to create a CASE construct for this, that replaces the numeric id value with the corresponding text literal, or something similar. Or you do it afterwards in PHP.

Comment: @CBroe yes, that is the ideal way, but I cant edit database. So I cant create tables.

Comment: ELT() instead of a CASE contruct should also work, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt - that is porbably the lowest effort solution you can get here.

Comment: _“I can have lots of size_id. They can be 20 or even 50.”_ - that would more be a point for _not_ stuffing this directly into the query IMHO, and doing it in PHP afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe man, that is unbelievable! Thank you! works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe suggested, I used:

```
"SELECT id, (ELT(`size_id` + 1 '" . implode("','", $array) . "') AS size FROM size_table;"
```

This is MySql and PHP code.
I use + 1 because PHP arrays begins from 0 index, but ELT starts from 1. And the quotes ('') are because you need to pass a string like:

```
ELT(`field`, 'first option', 'second option', 'third option')
```